# How to check if there's a ResultSet reading from a Statement in JDBC?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

Sometimes I have to query database while reading from a `ResultSet`. Is there a way to check, for a given `Statement` instance, if it is occupied with a `ResultSet` or not?

EDIT:

After reading @MarkRotteveel comment, I change my question from `Connection` to `Statement`.

He suggests that this is not possible and not a good practice either. So should I create a `Statement` for every query? And why I can't do this check on a `Statement`?

Comment: From the manual "A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set. " https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html.. Also `stmt.executeQuery(query)` throws a SQLException want there is a error meaning `while (resultSet.next()) {` would never be executed.

Comment: So you want to know if there is an existing ResultSet object associated with a given Connection object. Is that correct?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes!

Comment: @RaymondNijland Could you elaborate your idea?

Comment: There is nothing like that in JDBC itself. Technically a JDBC driver should support allowing multiple open result sets on the same connection (assuming auto-commit is disabled and you're using multiple statements). Why do you want this? And if you write your code correctly  your code would already 'know' this. If your code doesn't 'know' this, it suggests you are not managing your resources well enough.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So, can I do this with a `Statement`? I just want to separate `Connection` and `Statement` handling from my code.

Comment: Yes, create as many statements as you need.

Comment: I admit to you all I am too lazy to do that :)))))) So this is the only way.

Comment: I repeat, there is nothing in JDBC to check this, not on a connection nor on a statement. You should structure your code in such a way this is already clear. I still fail to see **why** you need to know this. Please illustrate your question with code where this is relevant.